# Where should I get my garden soil tested?

Tags: vegetables, soil, soil-test

This spring, I plan on growing vegetables on land that is new to me. How do I find a lab to test my soil? Will some labs give me information that others might not? Also, how much can I expect to pay for a soil test?

Comment: mentioning where you live (even just whether its the US or not) would help tremendously. in the US you can almost always do it at your local extension office, elsewhere it may be different

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I paid $17 through my state's cooperative extension service and got pH, organic matter %, phosphate, potash, calcium, magnesium, lead, and recommendations for how much lime and organic fertilizers I should add.

Your profile says you live in Ohio. A quick google search leads me to [the OSU Extension Service](http://mahoning.osu.edu/topics/master-gardener-volunteer-program/plant-and-pest-diagnostic-clinic/PSU%20Soil%20Testing1.pdf) -- note that the form indicates that Penn State's lab actually does the testing. The cost listed on that form is $9 for the analyses I mentioned above (minus lead); you can add $5 if you want an organic matter analysis. Follow the instructions on the form for taking the sample.